# Storage Gateway File Share - RefreshCache error: Too many requests have been sent to server

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to refresh the cache of a file share associated with an S3 bucket.

After running:

```
aws storagegateway refresh-cache --file-share-arn arn:aws:storagegateway:<region>:<account>:share/share-<file-share-id>
```

I got the following error:

```
An error occurred (InvalidGatewayRequestException) when calling the RefreshCache operation: Too many requests have been sent to server.
```

I get the same error from the console or from a Lambda function.

What could be the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like rate limiting. Have you tried contacting AWS support?

Comment: Thanks Tim. Today I opened a support case to see if they can help me.